Trying to create a CRC-16 CCITT-FALSE checksum - but result is incorrect
Hello I have the below c function which I believe to be in the correct specification for CRC-16 CCITT False:
uint16_t crc16(const char* pData, int length)
{
    uint8_t i;
    uint16_t wCrc = 0xffff;
    while (length--) {
        wCrc ^= *(unsigned char *)pData++ << 8;
        for (i=0; i < 8; i++)
            wCrc = wCrc & 0x8000 ? (wCrc << 1) ^ 0x1021 : wCrc << 1;
    }
    return wCrc & 0xffff;
}

I am using Objective C for my application and have the following:
- (IBAction)mycrc16function:(id)sender
{
NSString * stringexample = @"Example";

const char * stringAsChar = [stringexample cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]; //encode string into c string encoding

unsigned long CrcTest = crc16(stringAsChar,sizeof(stringAsChar)); // put encoded string date and size of string into the crc16 function.

NSLog(@"crctext %04lX\n",CrcTest); // print outcome to log
    
}


The output is always incorrect, the string I am testing with for example is giving a result of 6B20
However the result should be E272
I am using this site which I know to be correct to compare my results:
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html
Any idea where I am going wrong?

Please [edit] your question and add a C main function that feeds your test data into your function crc16 and prints the result. It would be best to embed the data in the main function. Otherwise, if it needs an input file, provide the input file as well. unsigned long ptr and (uint16_t )ptr++ << 8 look wrong. It looks like you wanted to use a pointer.

I don't know Objective C, but this looks wrong: const char * stringAsChar used as argument for a function that expects a unsigned long. Also sizeof(stringAsChar) is rather strange as it does not depend on the length of that string.

BTW: There is a code generator for CRC calculation with selectable algorithms and CRC models. see https://pycrc.org/

Yes you are correct it was meant to have pointers I was playing around with it and I must have forgot to put it back to its original state. I have simplified the CRC16-CCITT FALSE function with one I have found online instead (now replaced in my question), which seems a bit better put together than my attempt!
It's the Obj-C function which feeds the data and outputs the result (NSLog).
Still getting a wrong result with the new crc16 function B415 instead of E272 now.

I've compiled xour crc16() in pure c  and have compared some results like 1234567890 with the online calculator you've linked to and I get the same results

As suggested by @Gerhardh sizeof(stringAsChar) would be the size of a pointer (probably 8 or 4 bytes), not the length of the string, assuming Objective C is anything like C.

Hey Ingo - so do you think it's something related to the Obj-C code? would you mind posting your function for feeding the data and printing the result so I can compare what I have done to it?

I've already deleted the comment because it was a duplicate of @Gerhardh's comment, but: no. Objective-C is said to be superset to C so sizeof() should be as wrong here as it is in puce C. Just use strlen() if you have a nul terminated string. Btw. my main() is basically uint16_t wCrc = crc16(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]);

Suggested by this answer: "If your string is a C-String then you can use strlen(str)." Which would become strlen(stringAsChar) for your code.

This is correct sizeof was returning 8, I hadn't realised that was how sizeof worked, I have changed it to the string length and it's all working now, thanks for your help!

You have made the whole question useless by removing the erroneous code and replacing it by the workging code. What help could any visitor gain from your question now? If you find the solution to your problem, do not vandalize your post but instead post it as an answer to your own question.

What is the string encoding and what does defaultCStringEncoding use? "You might sometimes need to use this encoding when interpreting user documents with unknown encodings, in the absence of other hints, but in general this encoding should be used rarely, if at all."

@Gerhardh - I don't see the fix to use strlen() instead of sizeof().
